# How to setup a basic .gitlab-ci.yml file for CI/CD for a Python project using TensorFlow and OpenAI gym on GitLab?

Tags: tensorflow, gitlab, gitlab-ci, openai-gym

I think that the title is self explanatory. I'm currently developing a project in python3 using TensorFlow and OpenAI gym. I've already used some basic `.gitlab-ci.yml` offered from GitLab for other projects involving other languages but I've found nothing about Python projects with TensorFlow.

Comment: I know that this seems a classical _do it for me_ question without research on the problem nor code. I tried to find something to start from online but I found nothing. If you don't want to provide a full answer is fine but please, if you can, give me some hint to start working.